# Express Session not Saving/Finding Session

Tags: node.js, express, session, express-session

I am using express-session to try to use the session and it doesn't seem to find or save the session.

I would expect the response to increment after each call however with repeated requests with Postman or a basic svelte app, it keeps returning 0.

How do i get it to find the already saved session and return incremented values?

Node.js:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const session = require('express-session');

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:5000"); // update to match the domain you will make the request from
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});

app.use(session({
    genid: function(req) {
        return 1
    },
    proxy: true,
    secret: "max",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.session)
    if (!req.session.views) {
        req.session.views=0;
    }
    res.send((req.session.views++).toString());
    console.log(req.session)
})

app.listen(3000)
```

Basic svelte:

```
<script>
    export let name;
    let resp = "";
    async function sendReq() {
        resp = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/");
        console.log(resp);
        resp = await resp.text();
        console.log(resp);
    }
</script>

<main>
    <h1>Hello {name}!</h1>
    <p>Visit the <a href="https://svelte.dev/tutorial">Svelte tutorial</a> to learn how to build Svelte apps.</p>
    <button on:click={sendReq}>Click me</button>
    {resp}
</main>

<style>
    main {
        text-align: center;
        padding: 1em;
        max-width: 240px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    h1 {
        color: #ff3e00;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: 4em;
        font-weight: 100;
    }

    @media (min-width: 640px) {
        main {
            max-width: none;
        }
    }
</style>
```

Comment: After modifying the session object, you should do `session.save()`.  Also, why are you hardcoding `genId()` to return the same id every time?  Unless you have some specific reason for generating the session id yourself, remove this method and let the default behavior work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fetch()` by default does not send cookies with its request.  So, with no cookies, your server doesn't see the session cookie and then won't find your previous session object.  You need to add the `credentials: "include"` or `credentials: "same-origin"` option:

```
resp = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/", {credentials: "include"});
```

You may also need to call `session.save()` after changing the session object so your  change will persist.

Some other comments on your code:

1. For most sessions with a real data store behind them, you need to call `session.save()` after you modify the session object to assure it is saved back to the data store.  You probably don't need that for the default memory-based store, but it's a good general practice since production code will probably move away from the memory-based store at some point.
2. Your hardcoding of `genid()` to always return `1` will break a bunch of features in sessions.  Don't do that.  The default implementation of `genid()` will work just fine for your purposes so you can just remove that method definition entirely.
3. You don't show code for loading your web page from your server.  If you're not getting the web page itself from your web server so the `fetch()` call is a same-origin call, then you may also have cors issues (cross origin restrictions).
4. In your client code, you should move the definition of the variable `resp` inside your `sendReq()` function so it is a local variable and would not be trounced if more than one call to `sendReq()` were ever in flight by the same page.

Comment: Yeah, this is just a playground kind of thing to mess around and learn express-sessions just trying to get it to work at the moment. When i set `credentials: "same-origin"` it doesn't change anything. However when setting `credentials: "include"`. I get an error: `The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.`

Comment: Also, does postman just by default not save and resend cookies or is it just simpler to test in basic svelte app

Comment: Just found the problem, looks like you do have to call session.save() even with in-memory storage. If you want to edit your answer I can mark it as correct. Also, added the Allow-Credentials header set to true.

Comment: @yodigi7 - I didn't realize this was a cross origin request.  Glad you got it figured out.