# Express session resets session on every request

Tags: node.js, session, heroku, redis, cors

I have a VueJS project that uses axios to call a server on another domain. On this server, I need to save a few values in the session so they don't need to be looked up on every request.

The server is NodeJS and runs on Heroku and I'm using Redis for memory storage. I can successfully save data to the session, but on every new request, the system creates a new session with a new ID so I can't access the values saved during the previous request.

**EDIT**
After updating the code based on a number of suggestions, I can see the following error in the Network console on the session cookie:

```
Preflight Invalid Allow Credentials
```

**EDIT 2**
I was able to resolve the Preflight Invalid Allow Credentials by adding "credentials: true" to the corsOptions. This resolves the error I was seeing in network on the session, but I am still getting a new session ID for every request.

Code on the server:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const cors = require('cors');
var corsWhitelist = ['http://127.0.0.1:8080','http://127.0.0.1:8081']
var corsOptions = {
  origin: function (origin, callback) {
    if (corsWhitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1) {
        callback(null, true)
    } else {
        callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS - '+origin))
    }
  },
credentials: true
}

let REDIS_URL = process.env.REDIS_URL;
var Redis = require('ioredis');

const session = require('express-session');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);
const sessionClient = new Redis(REDIS_URL)

sessionClient.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log('could not establish a connection with redis. ' + err);
  });
sessionClient.on('connect', function (err) {
    console.log('connected to redis successfully');
  });

app.set('trust proxy', 1)
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({
    store: new RedisStore({ client: sessionClient }),
    secret: 'someSecret',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {
        secure: false,
        httpOnly: false,
        maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 10
    }
}))

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.options('*', cors(corsOptions))
// Add headers
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    if (corsWhitelist.indexOf(req.headers.origin) !== -1) {
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin);
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
    }
    next();
});

const getUser = async function(req, res, next) {
    if (!req.session.user) {
        req.session.user = "test@example.com"
        req.session.save()
    }
    next()
  }

app.get('/session', getUser, (req, res) => {
    // get the session id
    console.log('session id:', req.session.id)
    // the session will be automatically stored in Redis with the key prefix 'sess:'
    const sessionKey = `sess:${req.session.id}`;
    // let's see what is in there
    client.get(sessionKey, (err, data) => {
      console.log('session data in redis:', data)
    })
    res.status(200).send('OK');
  })
```

Method on VueJS:

```
getSession: async function () { 
  axios({
    url: 'https://server.example.com/session',
    withCredentials: true,
  }).then(res => {
    console.log(res)
  })
},
```

Comment: It could be cookie related.  See [Express session not saving/finding session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59327558/express-session-not-saving-finding-session/59327736#59327736).

Comment: In the network tab of the Chrome debugger, you can watch the axios call and see if it is sending the session cookie with the request or not and that's why express-session always makes a new session.

Comment: I did have a look at that answer before posting (actually upvoted it cause it solved part of my problem) but I’m not sure how I would make the axios call send the cookie.

Comment: Did you verify in the network tab of the Chrome debugger that it is not sending the cookie?  If so, try adding the `withCredentials: true` option for axios.

Comment: Yes the cookie is there, but when I add withCredentials it gives a CORS error. I've tried a few ways to solve it but can't figure it out. I updated the question and code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a number of changes required to make it work:

The preflight settings were being set twice, so in the code below, I needed to remove the second line:

```
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.options('*', cors(corsOptions)) //delete this
```

The headers I was trying to set under "// Add headers" didn't make it to the preflight request, so instead I needed to add "credentials: true" to the corsOptions and remove the code under "// Add headers":

```
var corsOptions = {
  origin: function (origin, callback) {
    if (corsWhitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1) {
        callback(null, true)
    } else {
        callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS - '+origin))
    }
  },
  credentials: true
}
```

Last but not least, the cookie settings in the session definition weren't working for a cross-domain request. Specifically, "sameSite: 'none'" and "secure: true" were necessary. Result looks like this:

```
app.use(session({
    store: new RedisStore({ client: client }),
    secret: 'someSecret',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {
        secure: true,
        httpOnly: false,
        sameSite: 'none',
        maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 10
    }
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same problem. My code working as long as it runs on localhost both (Client and Nodejs). But as I push Nodejs on Server it creates a new Session with each request.

**Note**: I am running Nodejs on http and I also tried all the combinations of session cookie settings.

Here is my Code

Nodejs on Server:

```
app.disable('x-powered-by');

app.set('trust proxy', 1); // trust first proxy

app.use(session({     // express-session
  secret: "MySecret",
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  rolling: true,
  cookie: {
    secure: false,
    httpOnly: false,
    sameSite: 'none'
  }
}));


app.use(cors({
  origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
  credentials: true
}));
```

Client Reactjs localhost:

```
// First Login request creates a new session for the user
const resp = await axios.post('http://my-host:8000/login', {
        "email": "me@none.com",
        "password": "hellokitty"
      },
        {
          withCredentials: true
        }
      );

// Second request cretes new session if Nodejs is running on a remote Server
const products = await axios.get("http://my-host:8000/getProducts", {
          withCredentials: true
        });
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34654390)